# Editing join table values in rails nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, has-many-through

Been stuck on this one for a while so I figured I'd throw it out there.

I have two models and a join model:

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :theme_containers
  has_many :themes, :through => :theme_containers
end

class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :theme_containers
  has_many :containers, :through => :theme_containers
end

class ThemeContainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :container
  belongs_to :theme
end
```

Grand. I know this association is working because in the console, when I type Theme.first.containers and Theme.first.theme_containers I get the models I expect (I've created the theme_container instances manually for the time being).

The issue is that in my form for theme I want to be able to update attributes on the join data, (theme_containers).

Here's a simplified version of my form:

```
<%= form_for(@theme) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :theme_containers do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'theme_container_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I run this, the container_fields partial is only rendered once and the builder object seems to be looking at the original @theme object. Is there something glaringly obviously wrong with my approach here? Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Also, I'm running rails 4 so I'm not using accepts_nested_attributes_for, and I have my strong parameters set up. I don't believe that should affect my specific issue but just throwing that out there too.

Thanks!

Comment: Several things - 1. Have you "built" the `theme_containers` object in your `new` action? 2. Have you include `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the `theme_containers` model too?

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is the following:

```
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :theme_containers
  has_many :containers, :through => :theme_containers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :theme_containers
end
```

and in your ThemeController:

```
def new
  @theme = Theme.new
  Container.all.each do |container|
    @theme.theme_container.build(container_id: container.id)
  end
end
```